# how to write "WITH CTE AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CASE" in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server procedure and I need it to be converted to work in mysql.

Below is my Mysql converted procedure that I tried but its not complete...

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SelectjqGridUsers` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SelectjqGridUsers` (IN PageIndex INT,IN SortColumnName VARCHAR(50),IN SortOrderBy VARCHAR(4) ,IN NumberOfRows INT ,OUT TotalRecords INT)

BEGIN

 DECLARE StartRow INT;
 DECLARE CTE VARCHAR(100);

 SELECT  TotalRecords = ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM  Users );

 SET StartRow = (PageIndex * NumberOfRows ) + 1 ;


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is my original SQL Server Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [SelectjqGridUsers]
@PageIndex INT ,
@SortColumnName VARCHAR(50) ,
@SortOrderBy VARCHAR(4) ,
@NumberOfRows INT ,
@TotalRecords INT OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    SELECT  @TotalRecords = ( SELECT    COUNT(1)
                              FROM      [Users]
                            )

    DECLARE @StartRow INT
    SET @StartRow = ( @PageIndex * @NumberOfRows ) + 1 ;


    WITH    CTE
              AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'UserID'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'
                                                          THEN UserID
                                                         END ASC, CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'UserID'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc'
                                                          THEN UserID
                                                          END DESC, CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'UserName'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'
                                                          THEN UserName
                                                          END ASC, CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'UserName'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc'
                                                          THEN UserName
                                                          END DESC, CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'FirstName'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'
                                                          THEN FirstName
                                                          END ASC, CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'FirstName'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc'
                                                          THEN FirstName
                                                          END DESC , CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'MiddleName'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'
                                                          THEN MiddleName
                                                          END ASC, CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'MiddleName'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc'
                                                          THEN MiddleName
                                                          END DESC , CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'LastName'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'
                                                          THEN LastName
                                                          END ASC, CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'LastName'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc'
                                                          THEN LastName
                                                          END DESC, CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'EmailID'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'
                                                          THEN EmailID
                                                          END ASC, CASE
                                                          WHEN @SortColumnName = 'EmailID'
                                                          AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc'
                                                          THEN EmailID
                                                          END DESC ) AS RN ,
                            UserID ,
                            UserName ,
                            FirstName ,
                            MiddleName ,
                            LastName ,
                            EmailID
                   FROM     [Users]
                 )
        SELECT  UserID ,
                UserName ,
                FirstName ,
                LastName ,
                MiddleName ,
                EmailID
        FROM    CTE
        WHERE   RN BETWEEN @StartRow - @NumberOfRows
                   AND     @StartRow - 1

    SET NOCOUNT OFF


END
```

Can anyone please help me finish this?

Comment: Hi, code writing requests are not really on topic on Stack Overflow. Can you point to a specific problem that you are having? You can edit your question.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thnx for ur quick reply ..how to write "WITH    CTE
              AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CASE" in mysql procedure...

Comment: You are asking to spend time and get the result to me ... Nobody will do this

Comment: @Sahal Sorry Sir But I am not asking anything like this.I need ur suggestion Sir

Comment: Just edit the question and write `What are you trying to do with that procedure`. No one will read you procedure to understand it..

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, there is no direct equivalent of a CTE (the `WITH` clause at the beginning of a statement) in MySQL. Nor is there an exact replacement for `ROW_NUMBER()`.

However, you may understand and (hopefully) accept the fact that a sentence in a human language doesn't always translate to another language word for word. In the same way, a SQL query written in one variety of SQL may not, nor does it have to, translate to a different variety clause for clause. To translate a query, you need two things, equally important: to understand what the query does *and* to be versatile in the target SQL variety.

The stored procedure you are translating implements dynamic paging of dynamically sorted rows of a specific table.

With regard to paging, SQL Server doesn't have native syntax for it, like MySQL does with its `LIMIT ... OFFSET ...` functionality. A probably most typical workaround for that, which you can also see here, is to employ the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and a subselect (in this case, the subselect happens to have taken the form of a CTE). How does that work? `ROW_NUMBER()` assigns numbers to every row in a subquery based on specific sorting criteria, and the main query simply filters on those numbers to fetch a *range* of rows, thus effectively giving you a page.

You need nothing of the kind in MySQL, simply because it offers you `LIMIT ...` and `OFFSET ...`, both of which, when used in the context of a stored procedure, can accept integer-typed parameters or local integer-typed variables as their arguments (well, they can [if you are using MySQL 5.5.6+](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html#id854806)).

And as for dynamic sorting, in SQL Server the sorting had to be applied to the `ROW_NUMBER()` function because it was used in conjunction with dynamic paging. But in MySQL you just go ahead and move the `ROW_NUMBER()`'s `ORDER BY` clause directly to the (main) query.

So, in the end, this is what I came up with as a replacement for the `SELECT` query in your stored procedure:

```
SELECT  UserID ,
        UserName ,
        FirstName ,
        LastName ,
        MiddleName ,
        EmailID

FROM    Users

ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'UserID'     AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'  THEN UserID     END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'UserID'     AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc' THEN UserID     END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'UserName'   AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'  THEN UserName   END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'UserName'   AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc' THEN UserName   END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'FirstName'  AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'  THEN FirstName  END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'FirstName'  AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc' THEN FirstName  END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'MiddleName' AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'  THEN MiddleName END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'MiddleName' AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc' THEN MiddleName END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'LastName'   AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'  THEN LastName   END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'LastName'   AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc' THEN LastName   END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'EmailID'    AND @SortOrderBy = 'asc'  THEN EmailID    END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumnName = 'EmailID'    AND @SortOrderBy = 'desc' THEN EmailID    END DESC

LIMIT   NumberOfRows
OFFSET  StartRow
;
```

There's one catch, though. Parametrising of `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` can be done in the form of a *single* reference (to a parameter or a variable) only, i.e. you cannot use an *expression* there. So, I had to use simply `OFFSET StartRow` above. However, it will get you a different page than the one returned by the SQL Server version *unless* you also change the `SET StartRow` statement like this:

```
SET StartRow = (PageIndex - 1) * NumberOfRows + 1 ;
```